# Has webpack.config.js been removed from Ionic 2 RC3

Tags: javascript, webpack, ionic2, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to play around with Ionic 2 for the first time using RC3. I'm struggling to get debugging working with Chrome using Visual Studio code.

I keep coming across references to webpack.config.js but that file isn't in the project created for me. Has it been removed in RC 3 or is something wrong with the project that was created for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

location is here:

```
node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
```